# Mac asking for password for some files when deleting

Tags: macos, mac, finder, sudo

This happens not for all files. When I move or delete some of the files on my external drive Finder will ask for password. Is it due to permission set on these files ? Can I use something like Sudo when running Finder to prevent these pop ups ? The reason I'm asking is that sometimes I leave the mac running to move some files from one disk to another, just to find it on the password prompt a few hours later. Thank you.