# Deleting files requires password and doesn't increase free space

Tags: macos, hard-drive, imac

I've been using my Mac for around 2 years, and 3 years overall with uni. I keep deleting files. When I do this, it comes up asking me to confirm my password that would normally come up after logging out and back in.

When I go to 'Trash', there is nothing inside the folder. Then, when I check my hard drive info, it just keeps going down in size, and not back up. Even deleting files over 1 GB in size. Makes no difference. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Lots of threads on this. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97726/deleting-files-doesnt-free-up-space be sure to edit your question to make it different than the other threads and we can reopen it.

Answer (score 0):

google a program called Grand Perspective and run that and you can see where the files are sitting as it scans your hard drive.

Comment: Right, I've tried that program, but can't seem to locate my Trash folder within it. SO i can't scan it to see where it might be hiding the files.

Answer (score 0):

First, solve the password issue when deleting files.  That should only happen when you delete things outside your home folder.  No space will be cleared when the permissions are incorrect.

[Mac asking for password for some files when deleting](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/89502/mac-asking-for-password-for-some-files-when-deleting)

Comment: Thats the thing, I don't actually have a password set up, it's just click return or ok, and it accepts it. It was not originally set up by myself, but by someone where the machine came from for university.

Comment: The problem is that the system wants to pop up he password dialog. Just because it's easy to enter no password, things are amiss if it pops up in the first place.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying dude, had a busy schedule. So, is there any solution I can do to stop this? I've found that if I send a file to trash from an external usb pen drive and then empty trash, it erases the other files that are hidden, because I can see the space on the hard drive increase. Just not sure what to do now. I'm not a mac expert yet. Still used to maintaining a windows PC.

Comment: It seems I have resolved the issue. I think it was because I hadn't run a time machine backup for a couple of months. Didn't want to keep adding more stuff to the drive. I managed to clean files by using a usb pen, adding files to it, and then deleting them cleared it from the trash bin. Since doing the backup, it has worked.

Comment: @dB9Project Excellent - I usually see this sort of thing on Mavericks and the newer OS where local backup snapshots can confuse people about what space is used after deleting the file from the filesystem - but I'm glad you worked it out.